# how to make an recorder player in react native using react-native-audio-toolkit

Tags: react-native

using the same snippet as given in example of react-native-audio-toolkit 
but getting many error while executing the code i am new to react native and trying to make an audio recorder and player and used many packages of react native to record

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-audio-toolkit/blob/master/ExampleApp/src/AppContainer.js

using this example to execute but getting many errors 
1.typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTAudioplayer.prepare')
2.Cannot read property 'prepare' of undefined react native